Styles from SCSS in React component library not applying in Next.js app
I have created a React component library using tsup to bundle it (turborepo), and I am using SCSS for styling. However, when I use the components in my Next.js app, the styles from the .scss files are not being applied.
In my component library, I have a Button component with SCSS styling.
Button.module.scss
.button {
  font-size: 64px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
}

button.tsx
import styles from './Button.module.scss';

export const Button = () => {
  return <button className={styles.button}>Click me!</button>;
};

tsup.config.ts
import { defineConfig, type Options } from 'tsup';
import { sassPlugin } from 'esbuild-sass-plugin';

export default defineConfig((options: Options) => ({
  entry: ['./src/button/index.tsx'],
  format: ['cjs', 'esm'],
  external: ['react'],
  banner: {
    js: "'use client'",
  },
  injectStyle: true,
  dts: true,
  esbuildPlugins: [sassPlugin()],
  ...options,
}));

package.json of component lib
{
  "name": "@dekada/ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/index.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/index.js"
    }
  },
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsup",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "dev": "tsup --watch",
    "lint": "eslint src/",
    "typecheck": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@dekada/eslint-config": "workspace:*",
    "@dekada/typescript-config": "workspace:*",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "esbuild-sass-plugin": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.79.4",
    "tsup": "^8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2"
  }
}

package.json of nextjs app
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "dev": "next dev -p 4010",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dekada/ui": "workspace:*",
    "next": "14.2.13",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.13",
    "sass": "^1.79.4",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


When I create the component directly in NextJS app, scss styles works just fine.
